# How to specify path to gorm structure file

Tags: json, go, go-gorm, go-gin

I have a `Products` structure:

```
type Products struct {
    gorm.Model
    CategoriesRefer   int64      `json:"cat_id" gorm:"column:cat_id"`
    Title             string     `json:"title" gorm:"column:title"`
    ...
    Image             string     `json:"image" gorm:"column:image"`
}
```

The JSON request will contain the `path to the image`, which is stored in another folder of my project(not in db folder), how can I specify this in the structure?

Comment: First of all, I would store images of products in something like S3, and use a CDN to access them. That said, storing images in a folder will not work, as the folder will not be compiled into the binary, so the images will not be accessible. To have the images be accessible you would have to embed them using the go embed package.

Comment: If the images are always in the same place relative to the Go code, and you always start the go code from the same directory (i.e. from the root source code folder for the project), you can just reference the files in the folder by prepending as many `../` as required to go up levels in the filesystem.

Comment: @ThijsvanderHeijden Yes, that's what I want, but I don't know how to write it correctly in the code, could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this should work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    ex, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    exPath := filepath.Dir(ex)
    imagePath := fmt.Sprintf("%s/../photos", exPath) // change photos to correct directory name
    fmt.Println("imagePath:", imagePath)
}
```

However as mentioned in comments this isn't a great idea as it will be relative to the directory where the compiled binary executable is located. You may want to use something like an Environment Variable to control this directory. That way way you can set it to different directories for testing, development, production, etc...